# DC blocking cap

Tags: capacitor, dc, dc-blocking

When is a DC blocking cap needed and when not?
In my case I have a two stage audio amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffB5V8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I read that is a good habit to have them on input (1), because you cannot be sure about the signal in integrity, so if that is ok what about the others? (2,3).

If I use a dual supply shouldn't I use DC blocking caps?

I am also interested to know if it is not strictly needed, if a good design should have them etc.

Please don't mind the values in the upper schematic

Comment: 1) Think about the **DC voltages** in the circuit if at the + input of OA1 a DC voltage of 0.1 V was present and DC blocking cap C2 was **not present**. What would be the **DC** voltage at the output of OA2? 2) if you can **guarantee** that there will always be 0 V DC at the output of OA2, you would not need a DC blocking capacitor at 3. Suppose OA amplifies not 1 x but 100x and it has some internal DC offset. Would there still be no DC at the output? A good design has DC blocking caps where they are needed. A good design also doesn't amplify DC if that is not needed (like with audio).

Comment: So you are saying that are more or less always needed? So to rap it up: at the input are needed for whatever signal is coming in and at the output because an OA creates some DC offset?

Comment: *So you are saying that are more or less always needed?* No I wrote: "A good design has DC blocking caps where they are needed." You have to consider the design and judge if they're needed or not. The "lazy" approach is to add blocking caps everywhere.

Comment: I would leave block 1 and 3 getting rid of 2 in this specific case. That taking care of incoming signals and the transducer.

Answer (score 2):

The DC blocking cap does what its name implies: it makes your amplifier have zero gain at very low frequencies (DC and close to DC; DC = 0Hz by definition).

Many audio sources may have a DC offset added to the signal. Such offset may be larger than the signal itself. So when you apply gain in the amplifier, that irrelevant DC offset may become a voltage much higher than the signal amplitude, potentially saturating the amplifier. Recall that an amplifier of the kind you are showing can't produce voltages higher than its supply rails (at most).

An audio amplifier that puts out a DC offset may damage the transducer at its output - say a headphone or speaker - since it'll dump much more power (due to combined DC+AC) into the transducer than the transducer was designed to handle.

In your case, the "blocking" capacitor on the input forms a high-pass RC filter with the adjacent 100Ohm resistor. The cutoff frequency is \$f_{hp}={1 \over 2 \pi R C}\$, here very approximately 1/(5 x 1E2 x 1E-6)=0.2 x 1E4=2kHz. That means that your audio amplifier will only provide full gain to frequencies above 2kHz. That's most definitely not what you wanted!

Change the resistor to ground from 100Ohm to 10kOhm, thus lowering the cut-off frequency by a factor of 100, down to ~20Hz :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am sorry I didn't mention that the values and the design are made up just to have a visual understanding of what I am asking.  My question was merely to understand once and for all when to use' em. For example: when somebody says with dual supply you can get rid of DC blocking cap isn't true? Why would you? Does the difference between single and dual supply comes from the fact that you bias the input to half supply rail and thus feeding yourself DC? But still OA may introduce always DC as also bimpelrekkie said. Hence are always needed (talking about Audio)